# Texturized torus surface

Tags: 3d, reference-request

I'd like to obtain a figure like the image below, with transparent (maybe white) background but for a torus surface.

I'm checking Google for hours but no success. Any idea where to look for?

**In resume:** I'd like a sphere and a solid torus with the same size (the same bounding box) and the same texture (not necessary the same colors as below) and white/transparent background. Also it could be nice if the view point shows the hole of the torus.

[image]

ps: I found (very pretty) this one (striped version) but the background is not white and it is not solid.

[image]

Comment: Why not make your own? Or commission somebody.

Comment: The second image is composed by [Villarceau circles](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Villarceau_circles). You can find some nice examples [here](http://home.online.no/~t-o-k/POV-Ray/index.html) with [POV-Ray](http://www.povray.org/) sources too. You can [edit](http://www.f-lohmueller.de/pov_tut/pov__eng.htm) the sources, remove the backgound and render a new image.

Comment: @PaoloGibellini seems to me they are torus knots instead of Villarceau circles. Because thet wrap around poles.

Comment: @joojaa, sorry but I have no idea how to do that. I don't work with design and so I only need some reference to look for the figure. I'll use it on a math talk. I could use another figure but I'd like both with the same texture.

Comment: Yes, they are knot torus. But it is only an example. If the torus is solid, it would be better. I'd like both surfaces with the same texture. I'll use on a talk.

Comment: @PaoloGibellini, thanks for your help but I have no idea how to use POV. But I'll look on the reference for other images.

Comment: @joojaa Indeed, they are torus knot (a POV-Ray render is [here](http://jholsenback.wordpress.com/2013/02/15/a-torus-knot/), based on a Blender export done with a [plug-in](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Extensions:2.6/Py/Scripts/Curve/Torus_Knot).

Comment: @Sigur You can use Blender [plug-in](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Extensions:2.6/Py/Scripts/Curve/Torus_Knot) or [KnotPlot](http://www.knotplot.com/) (or you can ask a friend to edit a pov file for you...).

Comment: What is the purpose and need. I mean rendering a solid torus is not exactly rocket science. However getting a specific look is hard necause there are so many knobs. Is the rainbow color a must or the sphere color? One could do a cuick lookup shaded toroid based on the sphere to get that exact look. Please document this in the post.

Comment: @joojaa, thanks. I edited. Since I'll talk about the topological difference between a sphere and a torus (like homology, fundamental group, etc...) I'd like them with the same visual (and a pretty one so students could be interested to create one).